# ¿Por qué no dibuja el arco en canvas?

Tags: javascript

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

for(var i=0;i<16; i++) {
  
  ctx.arc(50* i,50 * i,50,0,Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="800" height="600" id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

***Lo que quiero lograr es dibujar 16 veces un arco en canvas mediante un ciclo for, pero no me lo dibuja.. Por qué?***

Comment: Hace falta añadir el método [stroke()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke)

Comment: Bien pero me dibuja solo 1

Comment: Dibuja sobre el mismo punto ,es necesario desplazar en `x` ,`y` para esto, podría emplear `moveTo` o aumentar los valores como se añadió en la respuesta de @asantana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principalmente por dos cosas:

La primera es que no has marcado la linea, esto se hace con stroke().
Y segundo, porque en tu bucle aumentas la i, pero no hay ninguna variable en los parámetros del arc(). Si por ejemplo quisiera dibujar círculos en el eje x, podría ser algo así;

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var x = 50
for(var i=0;i<16; i++) {
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x , 50,20,50,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  x+=20;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="800" height="600" id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

También he puesto el beginPath() y el closePath() porque si no la línea no se levanta, es decir como si hicieras todos los círculos sin levantar un lápiz del papel. De esta manera en cada vuelta del bucle no empieza a dibujar donde terminó el bucle anterior.

Comment: Bien, pero no entendí lo del beginpath y closepath, por favor explicarmelo un poquito mas

Comment: vale, ya lo entendí y que pasa si nunca colocara el closepath? esque no veo diferencias si no lo coloco

Comment: Que aparte de los círculos, te va a dibujar una línea recta desde donde termina de hacer un círculo hasta donde empieza a hacer el siguiente.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.arc(x,y,radio, alpha, beta)` agrega un arco al trazado, y tú no tienes un trazado

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
var contexto2D = canvas.getContext('2d')

contexto2D.fillStyle = "#000"
contexto2D.beginPath()
contexto2D.arc(150, 150, 150, Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI)
contexto2D.stroke()
contexto2D.closePath()

document.body.appendChild(canvas)
```